Trigger backstage provider from backstage UI
We have a an api service containing data about developers and their software teams. This data is ingested into our internal Backstage platform through a custom entity provider. The data is provided as standard Backstage entities (software teams as Groups and developers as Users).
I would like to create som frontend code in backstage that allows users to create new teams and assigns users to the team. The api of our service expose endpoints for this. However, when I call these endpoints from backstage, the data is not ingested into backstage immediately, but first when the providers runs.
My question is therefore twofold:

Is it possible to trigger a provider directly from the frontend code, so I can e.g. show a spinner while the new data is created and update the current page on completion?

Can I setup the provider to run fast enough (including stitching) to process and ingest data to be available in backstage within a few minutes?


For context, we would probably want to enable full CRUD on the externally provided entities from the backstage over time, if possible.
For now the only solution I have found is to create e.g. a team from the Backstage UI and then show the user a message about the data being available after a while.
